# How can I download a numbered build artifact from Jenkins using Ansible?

Tags: jenkins, ansible, artifactory, devops

I have a Jenkins server that I'd like to download build artifacts from. The problem is that the way the job is set up, the build artifact includes the job number e.g. `NightlyBuild-346.tar.bz2`. We like the job numbers, because they make it easy to know how old a specific build is.

This becomes problematic because I don't know the precise name of the file I'm downloading--I just know I want the last successful build. I could do something like this:

```
- name: download build from CI
  get_url:
    url: "https://ci.contoso.com/job/NightlyBuild/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/NightlyBuild-345.tar.bz2"
    dest: /tmp/NightlyBuild-345.tar.bz2
```

...but this will break after Jenkins finishes the next nightly build, because the artifact will become `NightlyBuild-346.tar.bz2`. I think I have a few options here:

- Try to use wildcards in the `get_url` module (not so sure about that)
- Download ALL artifacts from the job (there are several) as a single `archive.zip` and use command-line and regex magic to find the actual build artifact I care about. (potential for a hot unmaintanable mess)
- Use the REST API to obtain the job number for the last successful job and form the full URL. (not sure that Ansible allows me to set variables on-the-fly like that).

Are these my options? Is there a better way to go about this? I want to eventually publish to an Artifactory repository from Jenkins, and if that's the right thing to do here, I'd appreciate some pointers in that direction too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query Jenkins about build number with [uri](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html) module:

```
- uri:
    url: http://ci/job/NightlyBuild/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber
    return_content: yes
  register: build_number_resp

- debug: msg="URL with build number http://ci/job/NightlyBuild/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/NightlyBuild-{{ build_number_resp.content }}.tar.bz2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Ansible 2.0` [maven_artifact module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/maven_artifact_module.html) is available. The module supports maven version coordinates via `version` parameter. Use it like this:

```
- maven_artifact:
    group_id: junit
    artifact_id: junit
    dest: /tmp/junit-latest.jar
    version: latest
    repository_url: htttp://your-artifactory
```

Comment: Konstantin's example is much simpler, but this is still a good approach.

Comment: When did maven and artifactory get into the picture? And how does it resolve the changing artifact names?